# Redeclare type helper in other unit, Free Pascal failed to compile

Tags: freepascal

I have this unit

```
unit helper;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}
{$MODESWITCH TYPEHELPERS}
{$H+}

uses
     sysutils;

type

    THelloWorldHelper = type helper(TStringHelper) for string
    public
         function world() : string;
    end;

implementation

   function THelloWorldHelper.world() : string;
   begin
       result := self + ' world';
   end;
end.
```

and other unit that redeclare this type helper

```
unit helperalias;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}
{$MODESWITCH TYPEHELPERS}
{$H+}

uses

   helper;

type

   THelloWorldHelper = helper.THelloWorldHelper;

implementation
end.
```

and program as follows

```
program helloworld;

{$MODE OBJFPC}
{$MODESWITCH TYPEHELPERS}
{$H+}

uses       
   helperalias;

var hello : string;
    world :string;

begin
    hello:='hello';
    world := hello.world();
    writeln(world);
end.
```

When I run

```
fpc helloworld.pas
```

It refused to compile with message `Error: Objective-C categories and Object Pascal class helpers cannot be used as types`.

If in `helloword.pas`, I replaced `helperalias` unit with `helper`, it worked.

I read about [helper restriction](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Helper_types#Restrictions_2).

Why is redeclaring type helper prohibited?

Comment: Because of that mentioned helper restriction, I guess. Your alias is not inheriting from it, nor is it doing any of the other things allowed.

Comment: yes i know that. I am curious about technical reason why there are such restrictions.

Comment: Then, if that is your real question, say it like that it in your question, and don't beat around the bush.